# Uploading images to Linux server through .NET API

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu

I have an ASP.NET core API project which lets users upload images. My first implementation was to use Base64 and save the images in the SQL server. However, I decided not to do that because of performance issues. The second implementation was to use Azure Blob storage and upload the files directly into the blob storage.

I am not sure if this is a good idea but instead of using Azure Blob, I would like to upload the images somewhere in my Linux server. Is there any special directory for saving files and would it be safe for me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no special directory for saving files in  Linux server which would be more safe.

All the folder in the linux is the same, if you have enough permission to access it ,then you could read and write the image in it.

Normally, we will add a folder inside our application to store the uploaded image, so that we could use relative path in our codes.

In my opinion, use blob storage is a good opinion. This will be directly access from blob url if you have enough permission and it is safety, we could generate the SAS to allow only specific user access, it is High durability and cheap enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes azure blob storage is one of the best options. However, i don't think saving the uploaded images inside the application itself would be the best practice and it might create some security issues for your app @brandozhang

Comment: In my opinion, you could disable remote access the folder in your application on the server. This will make your site more security.

Comment: yes this would be a good idea if i was trying to access the images from the same origin i can create a same origin policy in the firewall but this would not work with the mobile apps because of the request origin. I guess i have no other option but just make the images available to public.